# Can't make head nor tail of RSpec for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I had a set of tests for searching for a director by name which were temporarily more-or-less working for me.  Along the lines of:

```
describe MoviesController do
  before :each do
    @fake_results = [mock(Movie),mock(Movie)]
  end
  it "should call the model that looks for same director movies" do
    Movie.should_receive(:find_by_same_director).with('Woody Allen').and_return(@fake_results)
    post :find_by_same_director, {:name => 'Woody Allen'}
  end
```

etc etc.  This wasn't breaking anything too appallingly.  Unfortunately I then decided I needed to change my controller method to take an id parameter, not a name.  The second part of my code now looks like:

```
it "should call the model that looks for same director movies" do
  Movie.should_receive(:find_by_same_director).with(:id => 1).and_return(@fake_results)
  post :find_by_same_director, {:id => 1}
end
```

Now running spec results in the following error:

```
  1) MoviesController finding movies with same director should call the model method that looks for same director movies
     Failure/Error: post :find_by_same_director, {:id => 1}
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Movie with id=1
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:62:in `find_by_same_director'
     # ./spec/controllers/movie_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How come the absence of a real Movie with id = 1 is now causing a serious error - aren't my stubs/mocks covering me any more? There were no movies directed by Woody Allen previously. What do I need to do to allow my tests to satisfactorily pretend that a movie with id 1 exists?

EDIT:

The controller action is as follows:

```
  def find_by_same_director
   @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
   @movies = Movie.find_same_director(@movie.id)
   if @movies.count == 1
    flash[:notice] = "'#{@movie.title}' has no director info"
    redirect_to movies_path
   end
  end
```

Not sure whether this is expecting a hash or not...?

Answer (score 1):

Does the controller call `find_by_same_director` method on the `Movie` model with a hash or an integer id? If its the later then the mock as you have set it up won't work, because you are specifying that it must be called with a has `{:id => 1}`, so you would need to change it to:

```
Movie.should_receive(:find_by_same_director).with(1).and_return(@fake_results)
```

If you do specify a mock expectation with a `with` then the arguments passed need match exactly. If they don't match then the un-mocked `find_by_same_director` method will be called. If you want to mock a method for *any* argument then you can leave out the `with` altogether:

```
Movie.should_receive(:find_by_same_director).and_return(@fake_results)
```

EDIT:

Looking at the controller action, you will need to mock the `Movie.find` method as well as `find_same_director`:

```
Movie.should_receive(:find).with('1').and_return(mock_model(:id => 1))
```

or just stub it (if you don't want assert that the method gets called):

```
Movie.stub(:find).and_return(mock_model(:id => 1))
```

I also noticed that the spec mocks the `find_by_same_director` method whereas the controller calls `find_same_director`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Hmm, that definitely makes some sense and moves me forward, but now I just get a NoMethodError: undefined method 'symbolize_keys" for "1":String. Which doesn't mean anything to me! Maybe I need to start again from the beginning with some kind of RSpec tutorial...

Comment: Its hard to know exactly whats going wrong here without seeing the controller and model code. Looks like something is expecting a hash and getting the id as a string instead. As for tutorials, I found the RSpec book from pragprog very good.

Comment: Editing the question to include the controller code. I'll look into the RSpec book recommendation :D

Comment: Looking at the controller code you added I can't see any obvious reason for the error that you mentioned in your first comment. Do you have a stack trace for the error and what happens inside the `find_same_director` method? I have updated the answer.